# VISA: (Hex 0xBFFF0015) Timeout expired before operation completed

Tags: embedded, hardware, python

I'm writing a simple code in Python to remotely send commands from PC to RSHameg HM8134-3, using USB. I'm using visa to do so.

Something to note, when I write to it, it doesn't give me any errors(even though it doesn't change anything on the display as it suppose to)

```
rm = visa.ResourceManager()
scope = rm.open_resource('ASRL3::INSTR', write_termination='\n', read_termination='\n')
scope.clear()  # Clear instrument io buffers and status
idn_response = scope.query_ascii_values('*IDN?')  # Query the Identification string
print (idn_response)
```

And I'm getting this error:
[image]

Steps that I took so far to resolve the issue:
1. on the manual of the device, it's asking to have '\n' or \r\n in the end of the commands 
2. I checked it on NIVISA and it gives me the same exact issue.
3. Tried to increase the timeout
4. Tried different bauds (300, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200).

Any other suggestions? I'm stuck!

Comment: Does the instrument respond as expected to the `clear()` call?

Comment: I'm not sure. But it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Use Wireshark (Or similar capture utility that can capture USB) to verify that you are sending correctly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about PC programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a list of things to check:

- Make sure your communication parameters match in the PC and instrument, besides baud the RS232 are 8bit packets, No Parity Bit, 1-Stop bit, Xon/Xoff software handshake;
- Ensure you are using a "straight through" serial cable, there is also a "null modem" cable where the wires are internally swapped, they look the same, but function differently;

To be honest, I would try to get it to talk with Termite or Realterm first. Then, once you have things working there, try again in python.

Reading through the docs, you'll probably need to issue

`scope = rm.open_resource('ASRL3::INSTR', flow_control=visa.constants.VI_ASRL_FLOW_XON_XOFF)`

or some such thing.

EDIT based on comment:

Ok, if your device is using USB, this gets a whole bunch more interesting in a hurry. You will really need to do a:

```
>>> import visa
>>> rm = visa.ResourceManager()
>>> print(rm.list_resources())
```

if you do not see an instrument with a USBx:: type address, NI's VISA drivers aren't being used for the device and PyVISA won't work.

My **STRONG** recommendation is to use the NI MAX (measurement and automation explorer) program to ensure the NI-VISA drivers can see your device.

NI-VISA knows how to talk to a lot of different device drivers, but if it doesn't recognize your device driver, you can use the NI-VISA driver wizard to produce a new device driver for your instrument, which NI-VISA *can* talk to. THEN it should appear in NI-MAX, and then in PyVISA.

Alternatively, you could also use [Zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) to produce a libusbk driver for your device, then use [python-usbtmc](https://pypi.org/project/python-usbtmc/) to control it from python.

Good luck.

Example: USB type device appearing in NI-MAX. Note the USB0:: address.
[image: Ni-MAX Pic]

Example: Using NI-VISA Driver wizard to re-driver a device.
[image]

Comment: I did check everything from the suggestion 1 but still gives me the same error.  And for suggestion 2, I forgot to edit that I'm using USB.

Comment: Check the edited answer.

Comment: I didn't choose the write connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the error

> VISA: (Hex 0xBFFF0015) Timeout expired before operation completed

by updating the firmware of the instrument I was using (Rigol M300).